# django-fiber content template

Tags: python, django, fiber

I'm currently implementing **Django-fiber** on a project of ours. However I find the documentation very lacking. I'm trying to use **custom content-templates** for different chunks of content on the site.

I've added the

```
FIBER_CONTENT_TEMPLATE_CHOICES = (
('', 'Default template'),
('three-columns.html', 'Special template'),
)
```

However I cant seem to use the `three-columns.html` template, which I have placed in the template dir of **django-fiber**. The custom templates for pages works perfectly.

I would love some feedback from someone who's been working with fiber.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly how you have it setup but I just added PROJECT/templates to TEMPLATES_DIRS in settings.py.  Inside that I have a fiber subdirectory with my own templates.

Fiber settings like this:

```
FIBER_DEFAULT_TEMPLATE = 'fiber/content_base.html'
FIBER_CONTENT_TEMPLATE_CHOICES = (
    ('', 'Default template'),
    ('fiber/three-columns.html', 'Special template'),
)
```

If you are adding template by having an app then it will be looking for:

```
PROJECT/App_name/templates/three-columns.html
```

Remember if you change FIBER_CONTENT_TEMPLATE_CHOICES you will also need to update the database record.